# FxCopCmd in TFS 2010 vs Code Analysis VS.NET 2012

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, fxcopcmd

This question of FxcopCmd vs Code Analysis has been discussed in SO, but my question is a bit more specific. We use VS2012 for development and TFS 2010 for TFS Builds. My question is - Without having VS2012 installed on TFS, I wanted to know if VS 2012 version of Team Tools (FxCopCmd) could be installed on TFS 2010 so that I get same FxCopCmd output on both development env with VS2012 and TFS build as well? Today when I run Code Analysis in VS2012, the count of violations obviously is different from the count seen with FxCopCmd run as part of TFS 2010 Build. This is understandable due to version differences, though I ensured that both run with the exact same command line parameters. FxCopCmd references point to v4.0 .NET assemblies in both cases.

Can I just have VS 2012 version of FxCopCmd or Team Tools installed on TFS 2010 and would that provide same results as that of running CodeAnalysis on VS2012? (Code Analysis in VS2012 in turn uses FxCopCmd)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I just have VS 2012 version of FxCopCmd or Team Tools installed on
>   TFS 2010 and would that provide same results as that of running
>   CodeAnalysis on VS2012? (Code Analysis in VS2012 in turn uses
>   FxCopCmd)

Yes, this is possible.  You will need to specify a CodeAnalysisPath property value that points at the correct path, but otherwise the only concerns should be around licensing, not technical issues.